# Cannot resolve error in Firebase Chat application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im trying chat application using firebase. Im getting following error which could nit resolve myself,

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzble.class

I have mentioned below my gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'

compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.1.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.4'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FirebaseUI has transitive dependencies on a number of the Firebase libraries.  You must specify a version of FirebaseUI that is compatible with the Firebase libraries you are using.  The table of compatible versions is listed in the [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries).  The most recent FirebaseUI version is 1.2.0, which works with library version 10.2.0.  A version of FirebaseUI for Firebase libs 10.2.4 and 10.2.6 has not been released.

The safe change is:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
```

You could try 1.2.0 with 10.2.4 or 10.2.6, but may encounter the same problem you are seeing now.