# Android firebasui latest version

Tags: firebase, firebaseui

Which version of 'com.firebasui:firebas-ui:0.4.3' is relevant to Google service 10.2.6'?

I have synchronized Gradle.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44060126/4815718

Answer (score 1):

As of 5/19/2017 you want to be using FirebaseUI version 1.2.0.  The version you're using, 0.4.3, is very old and there have been many bugs fixes since then

1.2.0 is built against Play services version 10.2.0 but if you want to use 10.2.6 it should be compatible as long as you explicitly depend on all of FirebaseUI's transitive dependencies.  You can see them in the 'README.md' file.